# After adding to Always On Availability group the DB is at restoring state at secondary server

Tags: ag

I have some DB at primary server, and when I add it to AG it appears at secondary server at Restoring state. Why it happens and how I can solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question does not seem to be related to tag [`ag`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ag) - "The Silver Searcher, better known as Ag is a tool similar to ack". Please re-tag your question and/or give more details.